# Link error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol using private constructors and private friend function

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am new to C++ but not to programming. I'm developing a plugin and learning the language at the same time. The plugin is for old software but still being used, so I'm using VS2015 and an SDK to match. I'm having a problem that I just don't know enough to solve but I know that it's the result of something that I'm doing wrong or don't understand. Please also consider that I'm using a third party SDK, with only .H/.HPP files and an occasional .CPP, but that's it. Everything else is wrapped in their libraries. Therefore, I don't have the liberty to change any behavior.

My code snippets are parts of their headers (can't change) and the .cpp is my modified sample code that comes along with their SDK and which I'm using as my base. It is also the area of code that causes the link error. Their samples all work, I can compile them and run them no problem. My code also works and is doing what I want. Things only break when I use my modified code. The reason I'm doing this is because I need access to the message passed into the plugin and can't find any other way to get it other than to try and override "PluginMain". The original sample code actually does call into PluginSetup.cpp because it runs other code within it as setup prior to continuing on. I've only posted the part of my code which is my attempt to override the function as I mentioned and I just included the variable declaration that causes the error. If I comment my variable declaration and other code related to it, program compiles and works again. If I move the variable declaration to another .cpp file in my codebase, code compiles no problem. It just don't like being in PluginSetup.cpp but part from maybe the main.cpp file (which I can't do anything with), PluginSetup.cpp is the first that gets called. So this is where I chose to put my override.

1. Am I using the friend function correctly? As you can see from the codebase, they've made the ctor as well as the friend function private.
2. This may also go hand in hand with a question I asked before on how to instantiate a class from this implementation using private friend function and ctors?

Hopefully, what I've posted is enough to give someone all that's needed to figure out what the problem might be.

**ns1ns2Main.h**

```
namespace ns1

{

    namespace ns2
    {
        class Plugin;
        ...
        
    }
}
    
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __MainError PluginMain(const char* caller_, const char* selector_, void* message_);
```

**ns1ns2Plugin.h**

```
#include "ns1ns2Main.h"

namespace ns1

{

    namespace ns2
    {
        class Plugin
        {
            Public:
                static Plugin* const instance();

            private:
                friend __MainError (::PluginMain) (const char*, const char*, void*);

                Plugin();
                
                Plugin(const Plugin&);

                virtual ~Plugin();

        };
    }
}
```

**PluginSetup.cpp**

```
#include "ns1ns2Main.h"

#include "ns1ns2Plugin.h"

//-> My Modification Begins
__MainError (::PluginMain) (const char* caller, const char* selector, void* message)

{
    ns1::ns2::Plugin plugin;
    if (!plugin.instance())
    {
        plugin = ns1::ns2::Plugin();
    }

    if (strcmp(caller, kSPInterfaceCaller) == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(selector, kSPInterfaceStartupSelector) == 0)
        {
            bool bStatus = ns1::ns2::pluginSetup(&plugin);
            if (bStatus)
            {
                plugin_ = clpcsx::Plugin::instance();
                plugin_->startup();
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(selector, kSPInterfaceShutdownSelector) == 0)
        {
            plugin_ = clpcsx::Plugin::instance();
            plugin_->shutdown();
        }
    }

    return error;
}
//<- My Modification Ends

namespace ns1
{
    namespace ns2
    {
        void pluginLoaded()
        {
            // no-op
        }
    
        bool pluginSetup(Plugin* const plugin)
        {

            clpcsx::Plugin::create(plugin);

            plugin->setStartupCallback(NS1_NS2_CALLBACK(clpcsx::Plugin, CLPCSX_PLUG_INST, startup));
            plugin->setPostStartupCallback(NS1_NS2_CALLBACK(clpcsx::Plugin, CLPCSX_PLUG_INST, postStartup));
            plugin->setPreShutdownCallback(NS1_NS2_CALLBACK(clpcsx::Plugin, CLPCSX_PLUG_INST, preShutdown));
            plugin->setShutdownCallback(NS1_NS2_CALLBACK(clpcsx::Plugin, CLPCSX_PLUG_INST, shutdown));
            
            return true;
        }
        
        void pluginDestroy(Plugin* const plugin)
        {
            clpcsx::Plugin::destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

**Link Error**

```
1>PluginSetup.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl ns1::ns2::Plugin::Plugin(void)" (??0Plugin@ns2@ns1@@AEAA@XZ) referenced in function PluginMain
```

Comment: What is this `hns1` of which you speak?  I don't see it in the code anywhere.

Comment: @PaulSanders- Hi Paul, it was a typo... just saw it and corrected that. Thanks

Comment: How can there be a typo doing copy and paste?

Comment: where is the code for 'ns2::Plugin::Plugin'? Thats what the linker is complaining about. You have it declared in the header but there is no definition

Comment: @PaulSanders- I usually write out anything I post before. I must have hit a key inadvertently while crafting out what I wanted to say.

Comment: @pm100-All of the definitions for the .h files has to be in their library. As I mentioned, the code works fine without my modified code. So everything is already done and defined in their SDK. Even my code works if I comment out my declaration.

Comment: You should copy-paste code here, not type it anew. Otherwise your original errors may not get through, and new errors may. We need to see exactly what the compiler and linker saw. You haven't answered the question about `ns2::Plugin::Plugin()`, or provided the code to the compiler and linker. That remains the problem.

Comment: I though I did in my post as well as the answer to @pm100... The code definitions for ns1::ns2::Plugin::Plugin() is in their libraries I would assume. I do not have access to those. All I have are the headers. And for this particular problem that I'm having, the snippets shown is what's involved. As I said, I'm new to all areas so thought the description of what was happening would be enough to go on. I do realize from research where the problem might be I just don't know enough of the language to figure out the why. And please know that I'm not trying to be difficult. I appreciate the help.

Comment: So have you included their libraries in the link?

Comment: @user207421- Yes everything is there. As mentioned. I can comment out my code and it all works as expected. This problem only happens with my modification and in particular, it begins with the declaration. That is why I'm asking if it might be in the way that I'm implementing the quote unquote Friend function to try and instantiate that Plugin object. Why I asked about using a Friend function that's private along with the class' ctors. I can move that very same declaration to another place/.cpp and it will compile and link just fine. So it's finding the definition of the .h in their libs.

Comment: So what exactly is your modification? and what was the original? Clarity and completeness please.

Comment: PluginSetup.cpp was edited to show complete codebase. Though I don't believe that it should matter. I've been saying all along that if I comment my code in that file, everything works fine. Execution moves on. I only showed the declaration because that is where it stops. So it's not even getting to the code after that. I have removed the entire function __MainError (::PluginMain) (...) {...}, leaving just the original code at the bottom and the program works just like it should. PluginSetup.cpp is the first to be called in the plugin that's why I chose it.

Comment: What did the original code look like before your modifications?

Comment: Just remove everything in between //-> My Modification begins and //<- My Modification Ends and you have the original code

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the linker to include the libraries. Since this is VS you can add to the main .cpp file

```
 #pragma comment(lib, "xxxx.lib")
```

where 'xxxx.lib' is the name of the library that has those ns functions. You need to make sure they are in the VS linker path too

Comment: All libraries are added to project Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. They have always been there and is working normally. I'm using sample code as my base, so everything has been configured for their samples.

Comment: @kazon well the linker cant find the entry point, which is traditionally caused by not telling it about the libraries. Maybe you only updated the debug build profile? The other tink to do is look at the .lib file and see what it exports (EXPORTS command) and look at the .obj file and see what it imports (IMPORTS command). Also use procman to see where the linker is looking for libraries

Comment: @pm100- I will look at procman and dig around a little as you suggested. The point I'm trying to get across is that I've just been able to take their sample code, compile and they run. The only thing I think I had to do with any of them is to change where I wanted my output files to generate. Even with my modified code in place, there has not been any issues finding the entry point. This variable declaration and trying to instantiate the plugin object from this point is the only thing causing me problems. If I can understand how to get that done, I feel my problems go away.